# SQL Group Concat with Line Breaks

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to format some data and I'm to make it a comma delimited file, however I'm unsure of how to add line breaks into it as well. Below is the query:

```
select group_concat(line,',') as data
from (select concat(cast(date as string), ',',
                    cast(data_1 as string), ',',
                    cast(data_2 as string), ',',
                    cast(data_3 as string), ',',
                    cast(data_4 as string)
                   ) as line
      from [project:dataset.table]
      order by 2 desc
     )
```

How would I have this to include a line break?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

*Note: It is strongly recommended to use Standard SQL. If for some reason you are still in Legacy SQL - consider  [Migrating to Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql)*

```
#standardSQL
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(
        CAST(date_col AS STRING), ',',
        CAST(data1 AS STRING), ',',
        CAST(data2 AS STRING)
    ), '\n' ORDER BY date_col) payload
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

or

```
#standardSQL
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(
        CAST(date_col AS STRING), ',',
        CAST(data1 AS STRING), ',',
        CAST(data2 AS STRING)
    ), '''
''' ORDER BY date_col) payload
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If to apply any of above to below dummy data

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
    SELECT CURRENT_DATE() AS date_col, 123 AS data1, 456 AS data2 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-02-01', 222, 333 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-02-02', 444, 444 
)
```

result is

```
2019-02-01,222,333
2019-02-02,444,444
2019-02-06,123,456
```

Note - result is ordered by date_col because of `ORDER BY date_col` clause inside `STRING_AGG()` function